# How to parse extJS using Jsoup?

Tags: selenium, extjs, selenium-webdriver, jsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to parse the html of this link "http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/desktop/index.html" using `jsoup` but all it gives me is

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <title>Desktop</title> 
  <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application --> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- here it shows some script -->
</script> 
 </head> 
 <body>  
 </body>
</html>
```

How to extract attributes of the notepad icon there so that i can click on that using webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/desktop/index.html");

        WebElement notepadIcon = driver.findElement(By.id("Notepad-shortcut"));
        notepadIcon.click();

        WebElement notepadDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("notepad"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(notepadDiv.findElement(By.id("notepad-editor-inputCmp-iframeEl")));

        //Now you have the notepad DOM
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getPageSource());

        driver.quit();      
    }
}
```

**Side note:**

I tried using `HtmlUnitDriver` but as you can see [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-37240.html) there seems to be a problem.

Quoting user **nlotz**

> The JavaScript engine used by HtmlUnit chokes on the :first-childselector (used in >= 2.2.1).
>
> Workaround:
>   Ext.override(Ext.Button, { buttonSelector: 'button:first' }); (reverts
>   to the selector used in <= 2.2)

**Update**

The problem with `ChromeDriver` was that it was too fast. I had the same exception (`NoSuchElement`) until I put the debugger on. Then everything worked, because the breakpoint gave the web app the time
to finish executing the javascript code it needed. After some research this is what I came up with

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER.EXE");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/desktop/index.html");

        //This sets an expected condition for the icon. It has to be clickable in 5 seconds.
        //After that an Exception will be raised
        WebElement notepadIcon = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
                  .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Notepad-shortcut")));

        notepadIcon.click();

        WebElement notepadDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("notepad"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(notepadDiv.findElement(By.id("notepad-editor-inputCmp-iframeEl")));

        //Now you have the notepad DOM
        System.out.println("Page source: " + driver.getPageSource());

        driver.quit();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into the question. `driver.findElement(By.id("Notepad-shortcut"))` This line of code fails saying `NoSuchElementException` and moreover if this line worked i would not need JSoup. I want to use JSoup because WebDriver is failing to identify elements in a ExtJs page and i thought JSoup would solve that problem...You think my understanding is wrong??

Comment: Are you running the code I posted? It works fine for me. Your understanding is wrong, because Jsoup is a HTML parser. It cannot execute javascript, so the HTML that is generated on the client (from javascript) will not be available. ExtJS creates content on the client. Please run the exact code as posted. I used selenium 2.44. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just ran the same code with FirefoxDriver and it works fine but with ChromeDriver it is failing..Do you know Why? and once again thanks for your time for looking into this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I will look into this though and come back to update the answer. No problem have fun.

Comment: Hello again. As promised, please check my update for chrome driver.